# Vanilla Android allow direct SU/Root access

Tags: android, root

I am using a custom Android ROM for an embedded board and creating an initialisation/setup app that will need root.

I have been able to run my root level program using [Super SU](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.chainfire.supersu&hl=en_GB) no problem. I would like to bypass Super SU and have my app gain access to SU directly. Is this possible and if so, how?

By the way, I have the ability to customise the ROM before deployment.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the original Android [`su`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/extras/+/master/su/su.c) provided by Google.

Answer (score -1):

**It is not possible**

See how su work:When an app calls su the su binary get active and notify supersu app for and supersu prompts for root and then that decision goes to su binary and it performs that action

**When it can be possible**

It is possible when you use a vulnerability like `futex vulnerability` to `setuid()` to 0 and execute you command

Comment: this is how `su` from `SuperSU` works. There is also the original `su` without those checks.